# Nonlinear constraints with scipy

Tags: python, python-3.x, scipy, nonlinear-optimization

The problem at hand is optimization of multivariate function with nonlinear constraints.
There is a differential equation (in its oversimplified form)

```
dy/dx = y(x)*t(x) + g(x)
```

I need to minimize the solution of the DE `y(x)`, but by varying the `t(x)`.
Since it is physics under the hood, there are constraints on `t(x)`. I successfully implemented all of them except one:

```
0 < t(x) < 1 for any x in range [a,b]
```

For certainty, the `t(x)` is a general polynomial:

```
t(x) = a0 + a1*x + a2*x**2 + a3*x**3 + a4*x**4 + a5*x**5
```

The `x` is fixed `numpy.ndarray` of floats and the optimization goes for coefficients `a`. I use [scipy.optimize](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/optimize.html) with `trust-constr`.

What I have tried so far:

1. Root finding at each step and determining the minimal/maximal value of the function using [optimize.root](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.root.html) and checking for sign changes. Return 0.5 if constraints are satisfied and `numpy.inf` or -1 or whatever not in [0;1] range if constraints are not satisfied. The optimizer stops soon and the function is not minimized properly.
2. Since `x` is fixed-length and known, I tried to define a constraint for each point, so I got N constraints where `N = len(x)`. This works (at least look like) but takes forever for not-so large N. Also, since `x` is discrete and non-uniform, I can't be sure that there are no violated constraints for *any* x in [a,b].

**EDIT #1**: the minimal reproducible example

```
import scipy.optimize as optimize
from scipy.optimize import Bounds
import numpy as np

# some function y(x)
x = np.linspace(-np.pi,np.pi,100)
y = np.sin(x)

# polynomial t(z)
def t(a,z):
    v = 0.0;
    for ii in range(len(a)):
        v += a[ii]*z**ii
    return v

# let's minimize the sum
def targetFn(a):
    return np.sum(y*t(a,x))

# polynomial order
polyord = 3

# simple bounds to have reliable results, 
# otherwise the solution will grow toward  +-infinity
bnd = 10.0
bounds = Bounds([-bnd for i in range(polyord+1)],
                [bnd for i in range(polyord+1)])

res = optimize.minimize(targetFn, [1.0 for i in range(polyord+1)], 
                        bounds = bounds)

if np.max(t(res.x,x))>200:
    print('max constraint violated!')
if np.min(t(res.x,x))<-100:
    print('min constraint violated!')
```

In the reproducible example given above, let the constraints to be that the value of the polynomial t(a,x) is in range [-100;200] for the given x.

So the question is: how does one properly define a constraint to tell the optimizer that the function's values must be constrained for the given range of arguments?